# Parsing CSV file without standard delimiter

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, jquery-csv

I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery. I'm trying to parse CSV file where delimiter is not standard sign of comma (`,`), but something else(`;`).

I'm using the jQuery function `$.csv.toArrays(csv, options, callback)`. I'm aware that delimiter is supposed to be set in `options`, but I'm having hard time figuring how exactly to do this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is `$.csv`?  Do you have a link to that plugin?  Did you read its documentation?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Link to docs http://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
var options={"separator" : ";"};
$.csv.toArrays(csv, options);
```

Comment: FYI, the callback us optional unless you need to specify a callback function to run after the parsing is complete.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/blob/master/docs/api.md#csvtoarrays) you can override the delimiter in the `options` object like this:

```
$.csv.toArrays(csv, {'separator':';'}, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to [jquery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv), then according to the documentation available [here](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/blob/master/docs/api.md) you need to use the following:

```
$.csv.toArrays(csv, { separator: ';' });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var csv = "Joe;23;USA\n" + 
          "Attila;24;Hungary\n" + 
          "Li;20;China",
    options = { separator: ";" };

$.csv.toArrays(csv, options, function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

The `data` argument of the callback will be an array of arrays:

```
[["Joe","23","USA"],["Attila","24","Hungary"],["Li","20","China"]]
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/QJu2Y/) is the jsfiddle.